# How to check for the argument of a function and pass it on?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to code a function that takes one of my own commands and its argument if it has got one and passes on the argument only. Of course "int" is not in scope, but if I try to pass it on with x (like "f (x int)") I get a parse error. I'm new to Haskell and grateful for any advice.

```
data Command = PushC Int | Pop | Push Int
f :: Command -> Int
f x | x == PushC int = int
    | x == Pop = 1
    | x == Push int = int
    | otherwise = -1
```

I just want to check for any Integer as argument of the command and have it as output. If the command doesen't have an argument output 1.

Comment: Advice: read as much Haskell code other people wrote as you can. You'll pick up the idiom faster that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really should use [*pattern matching* [Haskell-wiki]](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) here:

```
f :: Command -> Int
f (PushC n) = n
f (Push n) = n
f Pop = 1
```

Pattern matching is more effective than using [**`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-), first of all, not all types are an instance of [**`Eq`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq), and furthermore you can not match *parameters* of the data constructor with `Eq`. You can thus *not* match `some_val == PushC num`, and hope that Haskell assigns a value to `num`, like Prolog does.

Usually `(==)` and `(/=)` are only used to check if two values are equal, not to discriminate between the possible data constructors and parameters of a type.

You could use a wild card (`_`) as last clause here, but it is probably better *not* to do that: if you later add an extra `Command` data constructor, the compiler can warn you that not all patterns are covered, and thus you can provide the correct expression. If on the other hand, you use a wildcard, then that clause will automatically be matched with that data constructor, and this might not be the intended effect.